# How to handle get completed POST request if 100:Continue in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, http-headers, express

I have a relatively large (50K) text file being POSTed:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:text/plain"  -d @system.log http://localhost:8888/
```

Testing using a proxy, I can see the full contents of the file are being posted.

However Express.JS sees 100:Continue in the headers, and a blank body. I have :

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

enabled, BTW. Here are the headers:

```
{ 'user-agent': 'curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5',
  host: 'localhost:8888',
  accept: '*/*',
  'content-type': 'text/plain',
  'content-length': '55909',
  expect: '100-continue' }
```

req.body is empty:

```
{}
```

How can I see all the data being posted in Express.JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that node is automatically sending the `100-continue` response as per the [node http module docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_checkcontinue) (assuming you are using a new enough node version). What I guess is happening is just simply that the `text/plain` content type is not a format that `bodyParser` can parse into something else (as opposed to json or www-form-urlencoded). So you can get your data from the standard `data` event which the request will emit for each chunk of data it reads.

Comment: that's correct. Using the data event sounds reasonable, I've also posted another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497358/handling-text-plain-in-express-3 re: handling the Contect-Type in Express (via Connect)?