# Empty req.body receiving text/plain POST request to node.js

Tags: node.js, http, post

Why can't I receive plain text sent in a POST request body?

The request made from a client browser:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/MyRoute/MySubRoute");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send("hello!");
```

Using Express with my node server:

```
app.post('/MyRoute/MySubRoute', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Received:"+require('util').inspect(req.body,{depth:null});
    res.send();
});
```

Logged to the console I get:

```
Received:{}
```

I've tried with `text/plain` (no charset), with the same result. If I change my content type to `application/json` and pass a simple JSON string it works fine.

Comment: `req.body` is what? maybe the `util.inspect()` function doesn't work this way with strings.

Comment: I also used console.log(req.body) without the util.inspect(), and tried JSON.stringify(req.body) and the result is definitely empty whichever way I look at it. ``typeof(req.body)`` is ``Object``.

Comment: Look here, answered by TJ itself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12497793/2083599 - this is not the optimal way of doing it, but its better than nothing...

Comment: Thanks very much - I hadn't found this because I assumed the problem was with my POST request rather than with Express not recognising the content type.

Comment: Express not recognizing the content type is not the issue. The real problem is that at the point you are trying to see the body you have not yet received it. By listening for the data even on req you then can get it. The end event is fired once it is all received.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Summarising the above comments which answer the question:

- The client's XMLHttpRequest is correct
- On the server side, Express uses [connect's bodyParser](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-bodyParser.html) which by default only supports the following content types:

  - application/json
  - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  - multipart/form-data
- Because the content-type of *text/plain* is not implemented by Express, there is no method to wait for the body to be received before calling the *app/post* route.
- The solution is to add the *text/plain* content type to Express as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497358/handling-text-plain-in-express-3-via-connect/12497793#12497793)

Answer (score 9):

Add

```
app.use(express.text())
```

You can read more about it [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.text)

Comment: please be sure to edit your answer with the relevant code rather than just a link.